# Вывод с определенным названием.

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, не могу понять как сделать, чтобы вывод файлов из папки были только с определенным словом в названии, вот код.

```
for($start; $start < $outimages; ++$start)
{
 $print = true;
 ($i & 1) ? $tpl = $settings['row_tpl'] : $tpl = $settings['row2_tpl'];
 $exploded = explode("-", $demos[$start]);
 $date = $exploded[1];
 $mape = $exploded[2];
 $mapesgabali = explode(".", $mape);
 $name = $mapesgabali[0];
 $year = substr($date, 0, 2);
 $month = substr($date, 2, 2);
 $day = substr($date, 4, 2);
 $hour = substr($date, 6, 2);
 $minute = substr($date, 8, 2);
 if($settings['del_demos'])
 {
    if($hour >= $settings['del_hour'] && $hour <= $settings['del_hour2']) $print = false;//echo $hour. ' - '. $settings['del_hour'].'<br>';
 }

 //парсим метки в шаблонах
 $tpl = str_replace('{DAY}', $day, $tpl);
 $tpl = str_replace('{MONTH}', $month, $tpl);
 $tpl = str_replace('{YEAR}', '20'.$year, $tpl);
 $tpl = str_replace('{TIME}', $hour.':'.$minute, $tpl);
 $tpl = str_replace('{MAP}', $name, $tpl);
// $tpl = str_replace('{HREF}', 'ftp://'.$settings['user'].':'.$settings['pass'].'@'.$settings['server'].'/'.$demos[$start], $tpl);
        $tpl = str_replace('{HREF}', 'http://creedgame.ru/demos/files/' . $d, $tpl);
 if($print)
 {
    $output .= $tpl;
 }
 else
 {
    ftp_delete($conn_id, $demos[$start]);
 }
 $i++;
}
// закрытие соединения
ftp_close($conn_id);
```